# How to link BluetoothSerial setDataAvailableCallback() to update text display

Tags: callback, react-native, reactjs, jsx

I'm very new to `react-native`. I'm using https://github.com/rusel1989/react-native-bluetooth-serial to connect my Android app to a BT device. This GitHub repo has an example, which works. I was able to send commands from app to device.

Now I want my device to send data back to the app. Think of it as IoT data, just a few bytes sent every few seconds. I know that `setDataAvailableCallback()` can be used. My question is that if I create a `<Text />` element in JSX, how can I link that with the callback. Thanks.

API: https://github.com/derektu/react-native-bluetooth-serial

Comment: My suggestion is that you do the tutorial on React: https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html, it will teach you how to update the `<Text>` element by setting state.

Comment: The tutorial noted above wasn't useful for this specific problem. This was more useful: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html#content

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by trying out a few changes on the example I had. Within `render()`, I included the following: `<Text>{this.state.myText}</Text>`

In the constructor of that class, I added a new field to `this.state` that is initially set to an empty string:

```
this.state = {
      ...
      myText: ''
    }
```

In the same constructor, I set up this polling at 100 ms periodicity:

```
setInterval(() => {
        BluetoothSerial.read()
        .then((res) => {
          this.setState({ myText: res })
        })
      }, 1000);
```

I will enhance this to read only when bytes are available. Also, my installation did not have `setDataAvailableCallback()`, which is why I couldn't use it.